# Accessing GCS from GKE pods

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-storage, gcsfuse

I have a GKE cluster with different microservices that need to have access to blobs in a bucket.
The same file may be accessed by different pods.
File can are generally big (4Gb).

Which is the best practice for such a use case?
I am confused if I should use

```
    bucket = storage.Bucket(client, bucket, user_project=project)
    blob_obj = bucket.blob(blob)
    blob_obj.download_to_filename(local_file)
```

or I should rather install GCS fuse or if there is a third method I am not aware of

Comment: Why do you need to download `GCS` big files in the `GKE` pods ?

Comment: I would love not to do it.... I am new in GCP..... How would you recommend I access data stored in GCS from GKE?

Comment: Can you check this [Article](https://jbrojbrojbro.medium.com/serving-up-data-from-cloud-storage-8d6af5c2fae9) once?

Comment: @Roopa yes, that's the way I am currently access data and it works indeed. But I am not sure if this is the best option. I think CSI driver, as suggested by sethiay, is better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use a CSI driver if you decide to go with GCSFuse. Google doesn't have a supported CSI driver yet, but there is [ofek/csi-gcs](https://github.com/ofek/csi-gcs) which you can find handy.

Answer (score 0):

According to GCP [doc](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcsfuse-integrations), an officially supported GKE CSI driver for GCS fuse is under development.

It will be compatible with the most update version of k8s, and have less limitation comparing the OSS community version. e.g. It don't require PersistentVolume mapping to a GCS bucket like the ofek version do.